# Using lambda to implement Singleton pattern

Tags: python, singleton

I'm trying to figure out why this code works, producing only a unique instance of class A.

```
def singleton_function (c):
    print("singleton_function")
    x = c()
    return lambda : x

@singleton_function
class A:
    pass

def test2 () :
    x = A()
    y = A()
    assert x == y

test2()
```

Output:

```
python3 test.py
singleton_function
```

Why is singleton_function only accessed once? A is of type function, so my guess is that when calling A, A(), it returns x, which is the instance of class A, so, it should have printed two times "singleton_function", since I am accessing twice.
What am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the decorator syntax:

```
def singleton_function (c):
    print("singleton_function")
    x = c()
    return lambda : x


@singleton_function
class A:
    pass
```

This is essentially saying that:

```
A = singleton_function(A)
```

And `singleton_function()` creates one instance of `A` and then returns a function that points to that instance.

So we get

```
A = lambda: x
```

Where x is an instance of the original class A. Calling `A()` returns `x` which is still that same instance  that `singleton_function()` first created.